# Magento: How to override vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote.php?

Tags: magento2, override-model

How to override vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote.php in Magento2.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to overide the entire file? or only particular function?

Comment: Only particular function

Comment: which function?

Comment: public function isVirtual()

Answer (score 1):

You can use preference to override the whole class

you below type of code in your module's **etc/di.xml** 
if only want to use for front-end then **etc/frontend/di.xml** or if only for admin then **etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<preference for="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote" type="Vendor\Custommodule\Rewrite\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote"/>
```

or if you only want to modify the reference class public method then best to use plugin and add below code in your module's etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote">
    <plugin disabled="false" name="Vendor_Custommodule_Plugin_Magento_Quote_Model_Quote" sortOrder="10" type="Vendor\Custommodule\Plugin\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote"/>
</type>
```

and in your plugin class use below type of code and use after method to modify the result of reference class method(or before plugin if you only want to modify the input arguments of reference method)

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\Custommodule\Plugin\Magento\Quote\Model;

class Quote
{

    public function afterIsVirtual(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        //Your plugin code
        return $result;
    }
}
```